# MVC 5 Not Auto Creating AspNetUser tables in DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC 5 and I am trying to configure Individual User Auth in a new database context created but the ApplicationDBContext isn't creating the AspNetUser tables in my new database. Can someone point me in the right direction on this?

**Error**

```
The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.
```

**IdentityModel.cs**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MyEntities", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MVC5.WebSite-20150723075149.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MVC5.WebSite-20150723075149;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.UserModel.csdl|res://*/Models.UserModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.UserModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=devserver;initial catalog=MyEntities;user id=user;password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I know MVC is supposed to auto-magically create the UserStore and associated tables but clearly I've done something totally stupid here. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried to put some data on it? EF don't make DB until you put some data and call `SaveChanges()!` method.

Comment: no theres no data yet..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I was doing something stupid. Basically trying to get the ApplicationDbContext to use a connection that was created by EF. Not the right way. To get the tables 'auto-magically` created. I needed to add a normal connection string to my Web.config connecting to the desired DB then set that in the IdentityModel.cs

**Web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MVC.WebSite-20150723075149.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MVC.WebSite-20150723075149;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Data Source=devserver;initial catalog=MyCatalog;user id=user;password=pass;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

**IdentityModel.cs**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MyConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Hopefully, this helps someone. Thanks to all who helped.

Comment: This answer should really be more obvious online. I'm doing a rewrite of an app that was DBFirst and needed to upgrade the database. All the other models came across nicely, just couldn't work out why it didn't do the auto create in the new database.

Answer (score 7):

Are you using code first migrations?

normally, you have to enable migrations, create new migrations and apply them in order to create your db.

Go in package manager console and execute the following commands

```
enable-migrations
add-migration initial
update-database
```

EDIT

if you don't want to use migrations, you can also put this in the constructor of your context:

```
Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext>());
```

but you will lose your data everytime the db is re-created

Answer (score 4):

If you need to recreate the tables, here's the generation scripts for ASP.net EF 2.2

```
USE [YourDatabaseNameHere]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetRoles]    Script Date: 3/27/2019 3:42:37 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles](
    [Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]    Script Date: 3/27/2019 3:42:37 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [ClaimType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ClaimValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins]    Script Date: 3/27/2019 3:42:37 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins](
    [LoginProvider] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderKey] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LoginProvider] ASC,
    [ProviderKey] ASC,
    [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]    Script Date: 3/27/2019 3:42:37 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles](
    [UserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC,
    [RoleId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetUsers]    Script Date: 3/27/2019 3:42:37 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers](
    [Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PasswordHash] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [SecurityStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEndDateUtc] [datetime] NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [AccessFailedCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetRoles_RoleId] FOREIGN KEY([RoleId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetRoles] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetRoles_RoleId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId]
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=yourservername;Database=yourdbname;User Id=yourusername;Password=yourpassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

just make this connection string in web.config then run the application,than register a account. check now your database.

Answer (score 0):

I am using DB first, modified [ExceptionLimeCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/798539/exceptionlimecat)'s answer to make it work on my system. With the answer unmodified it would not register nor allow login nor display the register link nor do the auto create magic but throw an exception on forcing it.
Here's the modification to the Web.config to make it work

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=devserver;initial catalog=MyCatalog;user id=user;password=pass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="MyConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MyCatalog.csdl|res://*/Models.MyCatalog.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyCatalog.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=devserver;initial catalog=MyCatalog;user id=user;password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

This maybe helpful to those who find the above answers complex or have some other challenge.